# Eclipse, PHP and Smarty

Tags: eclipse, smarty, aptana, eclipse-pdt

Can anyone suggest me a solution for the above mentioned combination. I'm using Eclispe Helios SR1 with latest PDT from Zend and Aptana Studio 2 Eclipse plugin. Otherwise it all works well, with Aptana Editor for HTML/Template files and PDT for PHP stuff, but Smarty syntax highlighting on templates would be nice. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using PHPEclipse for years - it has Smarty syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. Seems somewhat more limited that PDT though, or maybe I just can't configure it right... There's no code assist for functions?